# Замена индекса на указатель в цикле

Tags: c, оптимизация, арифметика

Пытаюсь произвести машинно-зависимую оптимизацию: замена индекса на указатель.

```
            c = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++)
            {
                c = c + a[i] - b[i] + 10;
                a[i] = c % 10;
                c = (c < 10) ? -1 : 0;
            }
            while ((a[a[0]] == 0 && a[0] > 1)) a[0] = a[0] - 1;
```

Массив *а* не динамический и его длинна - N+5.В а[0] лежит количество цифр числа, а каждая остальная ячейка от a[1] до a[N+5-1] - это цифры числа,лежащие в обратном порядке.
Например, число 459 в массиве а будет записано так :

```
a[0]=3//кол-во цифр в числе
a[1]=9//самая последняя цифра числа 459
a[2]=5//средняя цифра числа 459
a[3]=4//первая цифра числа 459
```

Цифры в массиве *b* хранятся таким же образом.
Хочу для оптимизации вычитания применить замену индекса на указатель:

```
            int* pointer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(N + 5));
            int* pointer1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(N + 5));
            memcpy(pointer, a, N + 5);
            memcpy(pointer1, b, N + 5);
            start = clock();
            c = 0;
            int K = a[0];
            for (pointer=&a[1]; pointer <= &pointer[K]; pointer++,pointer1++)
            {
                c = c + (*pointer) - (*pointer1) + 10;
                (*pointer) = c % 10;
                c = (c < 10) ? -1 : 0;
            }
            while ((*(pointer+K) == 0 && (*pointer) > 1)) (*pointer) = (*pointer) - 1;
```

Сначала просто пытался создать отдельные указатели на массив *a* и *b*, но мне этот вариант показался неверным.Поэтому просто создал указатели и выделил на них памяти,скопировал содержимое а и b соответственно.Но всё равно эта реализация ошибочна,как возможно это исправить?

Comment: Как раз выделять память и копировать данные неверно. Делаете указатели на `a`, `b`, конец `a` и вперед

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно  так:

```
int *pa = a, n_digits = *pa++, *pb = b, *pe = a + n_digits, c = 0;
while (pa < pe) {
  c = c + *pa - *pb++ + 10;
  *pa++ = c % 10;
  c = (c < 10) ? -1 : 0;
}
pe--;

while (*pe-- == 0)
  n_digits--;
a[0] = n_digits;
```

Comment: ,но ведь в pa[0] должно хранится кол-во цифр числа, но там в pa[0] лежит уже первое с конца

Comment: дошло, спасибо большое